# Game's anti-cheat complains when driver test-signing mode is on

Tags: windows, x86-64, kernel-mode, driver

I use Windows 7 64 bit, thus in order to load a test-signed driver, I need to enable test-signing mode.

My driver bypasses some of the game's anti-cheat features to allow me to run a debugger and attach to the program.

However, when I enable the test-signing mode and launch the game, its anti-cheat service detects test-signing is enabled and terminates the game.

I also tried to disable the driver signature enforcement by restarting the computer and pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>, although the result is the same.

I thought about a possible solution: set the `g_CiEnabled` variable to `TRUE` after the game's run (however, as I can't run my driver, I'd need to find a vulnerability in a signed driver and set it from there, although I think it's not worth doing all that stuff.).

Is there an easier way to run the test-signed driver on 64 bit system without test-signing mode?

Comment: What about, using your driver, disabling the test-signing in-game check, so that the game will not terminate when test-signing is on?

Comment: @nirlzr AFAIK, to enable/disable test-signing, one needs to restart computer

Comment: You are correct but I'm not suggesting you enable/disable test-signing. I suggest you *patch* the piece of code that tests whether test-signing is enabled *in the game executable*.

Comment: @NirIzr Oh, you're right! I don't know why I didn't think about it earlier, maybe I thought it can be bypassed easier. Thanks!

Comment: Great, let me turn that to an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the answer can really be more simple then you'd think.

One approach you could take is that instead of getting your driver to load without test-signing (which seems to be your initial direction of approach), you could *prevent the debugged executable from detecting test-signing it on*.

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e6c1be93-7003-4594-b8e4-18ab4a75d273/detecting-testsigning-onoff-via-api?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) is a link with a few suggestions on how one may detect if test-signing is enabled or not, you can search for similar looking code (e.g. calls to `NtQuerySystemInformation` with the [`SystemCodeIntegrityInformation`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/km/ntoskrnl/api/ex/sysinfo/codeintegrity.htm)).

An alternative solution if your main goal is researching the executable at hand, you could consider using windows versions *prior to Vista*, where loading your own drivers is far easier.